# Create Entity Framework Without t4 code generator (like vs 2010)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to create an Entity Framework Model based on database using VS 2015.

There is some problem:

1) When I want to create model I get this warning:

[image]

2) When I create mode some file being generate like T4.

[image]

3) Generated class hasn't Data Annotations like :

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="SomeModel", Name="tblCode1")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
```

4) In our group there are some people that have VS 2013 or 2010 that they can't use this type of models.

How I can create model using VS 2015 like VS 2010 or 2013 without T4 (Just 2 files like below)

[image]

Comment: Are you speaking about changing the Code Generation Strategy to Legacy ObjectContext? Can't believe it could be simple as that, but asking just in case.

Comment: Specify in more details what needs to be recoded. What syntax you're parsing and how it looks like ?

I've seen .tt templates, but from my perspective it's bit overkill, it's much more easier to construct your own parser, but you need to know some basics about parser construction (tokenizing, semantic tree construction), but also bit about language which you want to parse.

I've could code you demo parser, but need to know bit deeper what you're parsing here.

Comment: Yes, this is ObjectContext API. It used to be the "default" in Code Generation Strategy of the edmx. I don't know if that's still true in VS2015 (haven't got it installed here). You probably forgot about some steps you and your colleagues took in the past after starting to use a new installation of VS20xx, because DbContext has been the pre-set Code Generation Strategy since, I believe, EF 4.3. This message is one that everybody clicks away the first time (with don't show again) and then forget about. But now the most important remark: do everything you can to move to DbContext!

Comment: Oh, and this "default" Code Generation Strategy was not selected by default. The default option has long been "None", which in reality is not "none" but t4. Now whoever still understands this, congratulations!

Comment: @GertArnold In VS2013/2015 the option is called "T4" :) And is the default.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380820/change-ef-6-code-generation-strategy-from-t4?lq=1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You need to change the `Code Generation Strategy` property of the `edmx` from "**T4**" to "**Legacy ObjectContext**" and delete the `.tt` nodes from the Solution Exporer.

**Long answer:**

Here are the steps needed:

(1) Assuming you start by selecting "*Add -> New Item -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> EF Designer from database*".

(2) Follow the "*Entity Data Model Wizard*". The next is **very important**. When you get to the screen which asks you for the EF version you want to use, make sure you select **EF 5.0**, otherwise T4 template will be the only option you have:

[image]

(3) Finish the wizard. Say OK to security warnings like your first screenshot. The project structure will look like your second screenshot.

(4) Open the `edmx` file in a designer. Look at the Properties Window, there is a property called `Code Generation Strategy` which by default is "**T4**"

[image]

Change the property to "**Legacy ObjectContext**"

(5) Delete *YourModel.Context.tt* and *YourMdel.tt* nodes from the Solution Explorer and you are done.

A bit boring, but does what you want. The drawback is that you are limited to an outdated EF version, and the upcoming EF7 will retire `edmx` at all, so it might be a good time to start thinking of switching to the Code First approach. But until then, hope the above will help to keep your current process.

Answer (score 2):

For generate "Code first" model (obtain a code first model starting from database) you can also use Code Smith Generator. You can start from POCO classes templates (or from NHibernate templates if you need serialization, IDataErroInfo, INotifyPropertyChanged, and so on implemented) and customize them is really simple (the syntax is based on ASP). Probably there is also a free version.

Looking around I found also an article and an open source tool that extract POCO classes from SQL Server database.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/892233/POCO-Generator

Comment: I have worked with EF for years using both EDMX and Code First.
I strongly advice you to use Code First like Bubi suggests.  It is a small learning curve but much better and it will be much easier for you to upgrade to EF7 when it is released and you are ready to upgrade.   
With Code First you can get true POCO classes and there is no T4.