# how to change Code Generation Strategy in VS2015?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using VS2015 and running into following error, dont see any such property as `Code Generation Strategy` in my property window as shown in screen shot,how can I find this propery?

```
// T4 code generation is enabled for model 'C:\Users\username\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\EFdemo\EFdemo\EmployeeModel.edmx'. 
// To enable legacy code generation, change the value of the 'Code Generation Strategy' designer
// property to 'Legacy ObjectContext'. This property is available in the Properties Window when the model
// is open in the designer
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your designer (xxxxx.edmx)
2. Click on the background of the designer
3. See the Properties windows. You will find it here

[image]

Comment: Hey, I am trying to change the Code Generation Strategy as well, so  I can use ObjectContext rather than DbContext. Our whole legacy app is built around using ObjectContext. I found this property, however, like in your picture it appears to be read-only and I am not able to change it? Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: @Mitch You can try this answer as reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27514225/3097810